# CSS removed in output html code - kolkov/angular-editor

Tags: angular, html-editor, kolkov-editor

When loading the page with default Html code the **editor UI** and the **output Html** code work as expected, if any action performs in the editor then the UI looks good but **the output Html code has removed all the css changes**.

I have created stackblitz code here for a better understanding of my issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-editor-wysiwyg-i

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: tbh kolkov angular editor have lot of problems. I used it in the past for one of my project, but I then migrated to tinymce. Just check the number of [open issues](https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor/issues) and how responsive the maintainers are, to these issues.

Comment: @SagarV, thank you for your suggestion tinymce, It looks interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to disable sanitization by setting the option `sanitize` to false in your config object in `app.component.ts`

```
config: AngularEditorConfig = {
    ....
    sanitize: false,
    ....
  };
}
```

check the library documentation here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kolkov/angular-editor